# Hide/Show Label and Paragraph from select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide my label for gvw and the `<p>` after it I only want it to show when Truck is chosen. Can someone please help me and explain to me how to do it using this code? The problem is the placement of them otherwise it could be easier with jQuery :/

http://jsfiddle.net/1xqbpLp1/

```js
 function GVW(){
   var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('vehiclebody');
   var textbox = document.getElementById('gvw');
   // Array for storing whether the textbox is required
   var is_required = [false, false, false, false, true, false];
     
   if(is_required[dropdown1.selectedIndex]) {
       textbox.required = true;
       textbox.style.display = "inline-block";
   } else {
       textbox.value = "";
       textbox.required = false;
       textbox.style.display = "none";  
   }

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="vehiclebody" id="vehiclebody" required="yes" message="Please select body." size="1"  onChange="GVW();">
    <option value="">Choose a Vehicle</option>
    <option value="0">2Dr</option>
    <option value="1">Pickup</option>
    <option value="2">4dr</option>
    <option value="3">Truck</option>
    <option value="4">Convertible</option>
    <option value="5">Van</option>
</select>


<label for="ew">Empty Weight:</label>
         <input type="text" name="ew" id="ew" validateat="onSubmit" validate="noblanks" required="yes" message="Please enter empty weight." value="">
         
         <label for="gvw">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gross Vehicle Weight:*</label>
         <input type="text" name="gvw" id="gvw" onfocus="this.select()" required="yes" message="Please enter gross vehicle weight." value="" style="display:none;">
         
         </p>  
         </div>
         
         <p>*Gross Vehicle Weight is required for heavy trucks over 5000 lbs. Visit our website for more information.&nbsp;<a href="http://www.taxcollector.com/services_vehicle_heavy_truck.asp" target="_blank">Heavy Truck Information and Fee Schedule based on GVW</a> </p>
```

Comment: can you give the `p` an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CSS to initially hide the elements:

```
<p id="gvwInfo" style="display:none">
```

And then use JavaScript to show/hide them depending on the selection. Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgajera/1xqbpLp1/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'd take out your inline onchange="" and just go..

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() =="3") {
        $("label[for='gvw']").toggle();        
    }
});
```